# how to select the highest rating item if the Ids are the same (distinct)?

Tags: c#, distinct

I have two lists which contains the Id, Type and Rating. 
I union those two lists and distinct them by Id using moreLinq. However, I am getting the rating which is added to the list later. I would like to be able to distinct them with Id and get the item which have the most rating.

```
item1.Union(item2).DistinctBy(e => e.Id);
where item1 is a baseItem of 
BaseItem{
     Id, 
     Type,
     Rating,
}
```

It is always giving me the ratings of item2 if their Ids are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group, order, and take the first item (and you don't need `MoreLinq` for this anymore):

```
var result = item1.Union(item2)
                  .GroupBy(e => e.id)
                  .Select(g => 
                      g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rating).First()
                  );
```

Comment: This is a great one. I was so focused on trying to do as distinct function and did not think about this possibility. Thanks you for the answer but I changed First() into FirstOrDefault().

Comment: @ChitKhine Not a problem, glad to help. In regards to `FirstOrDefault()` - you are *guaranteed* to always have at least one item in a grouping (otherwise the grouping wouldn't exist). To me, writing `FirstOrDefault()` may be misleading to readers - though I do concede it may be a matter of preference with no real impact